# Stuck on deferreds with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

I'm stuck.  This makes no sense.

This following line of code calls loadJSONfile, and then sets up a call to dataLoaded when the getJSON resolves.

```
$.when(loadJSONfile(pathToLoad + "/" + fileToLoad,provIdx)).done(dataLoaded);
```

Here's loadJSONfile:

```
function loadJSONfile(pathToFile,idx1,idx2,num2,idx3,num3,dir) {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    //var IDX = idx;
    /* code to load the stuff goes here */
    $.getJSON(pathToFile).done(function(data) { 

        deferred.resolve(data,idx1,idx2,num2,idx3,num3,dir);
    }).fail(function() { console.log('FAILED') });

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

The following line of code calls loadMapData, and sets up a call to mapDataLoaded wheen loadMapData resolves:

```
$.when(loadMapData(provinceEntry,regionIdx)).done(mapDataLoaded);
```

Here's loadMapData:

```
function loadMapData(provinceEntry,regionIdx) {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var regionCode = provinceEntry.regions[regionIdx];

    $.getJSON('data/topojson' + String(provinceEntry.Number) + String(regionCode) + '.topojson').done(function(topoData) {

        deferred.resolve(topoData,provinceEntry,regionIdx);
    })
}
```

But it doesn't work.  The code resovles the deferred instantly, which obviously causes mapDataLoaded to fail.

Why does one work when the other, which is identical, not work?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but they aren't identical, because your first function returns a promise, and your second function doesn't return anything.

Comment: ^ `loadMapData` doesn't return a promise

Comment: And you don't need `$.Deferred` here, just do `return $.getJSON(...)` as it already returns a promise.

Comment: First - OMG I can't believe it - isn't it just the thing, the blatantly obvious thing gets missed.  Second, thanks for the advice on the deferred stuff.  There is a reason I'm using it here, which I explain in a comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadMapData()` is not returning anything.  It must return a promise for `$.when()` to do its job like you are doing in `loadJSONfile()`.

But, I must say, you're using some anti-patterns for promises (creating new promises when you don't need to).

Here's a fixed `loadMapData()` without the anti-patterns and returning a promise:

```
function loadMapData(provinceEntry,regionIdx) {
    var regionCode = provinceEntry.regions[regionIdx];
    return $.getJSON('data/topojson' + provinceEntry.Number + regionCode + '.topojson');
}

loadMapData(provinceEntry,regionIdx).then(function(topoData) {
    // you can refer to topoData, provinceEntry and regionIdx here
    mapDataLoaded(topoData, provinceEntry,regionIdx);
}, function(err) {
    // error handling here
});
```

The key to avoiding the anti-pattern is to avoid creating a new promise when `$.getJSON()` already returns one so you just use the promise that is already being returned.

---

And, a word about `$.when()`.  First off, you MUST pass it one or more promises.  It has no magic power to know when some async function you pass it is actually done.  It only knows how to use promises.  And, secondly, there is zero reason to use `$.when()` unless you are trying to coordinate more than one promise.  If you have just a single promise, you can just use `.then()` on the promise itself (like I did on the `loadMapData()` above - there's no need to wrap it in `$.when()`.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer 50 times, because it's great.  

The reason for the so-called anti-pattern approach is I discovered the hard way that I needed to slow down the accessing of the data, to avoid a ridiculous amount of requests happening virtually simultaneously.  

The dataset is broken up into about 60,000 small JSON files in total so I needed to set it up so it wouldn't request the next one until the first one had loaded, or it would cause the server to swear at me. (I tried).  Thus using a nested promise approach - the data load finishing triggers loading the next one.

Comment: However since implementing the load-the-data-first design pattern, I discovered that it took 15-20 minutes to download everything, which is obviously crazy, so I'm re-vamping the approach anyway.  That said, I do like the idea of load-data -> load-topojson -> display on map -> get next part of data.  Eye candy.